# UUID for ios device

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am using IBM MFP version 8 and cordova device plugin. On the IBM console, I see that my device is register with a device Id. However, I getting a different value when I execute device.uuid..

How can I get the same id that is store in MFP

Product version: 8.0.0.00-20170220-1900

Thanks

Comment: In which mobile os environment you are trying this ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The device ID generated by MobileFirst is not same as the value you obtain when you execute `device.uuid` API using `cordova-plugin-device`.

If you wish to store unique ID for each device in MFP, you can use  `getDeviceDisplayName` and `setDeviceDisplayName` APIs to retrieve and store the unique names/ID.

More details about API's can be found [here](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/api-ref/wl-client-js-apidoc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Client.html#setDeviceDisplayName).